# Different text editor in .net development environment

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

Is it possible to have our own text editor in .net development environment such as notepad++ and intellicense enabled?

Comment: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/notepad-c-compiler-you-can-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about notepad++, but you can use [vim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329)